# Error in curlOptions(..., .opts = .opts) : unnamed curl option(s):

Tags: r, rcurl

When I use the below command
    curlPerform(url = "Intranet URL Here",getURL("Intranet URL Here",userpwd = "USERID:PASSWORD",cainfo=system.file("CurlSSL","cacert.pem",package="RCurl")),
    httpheader = headerfields,postfields = body,writefunction = reader$update)

I am getting the error message as mentioned below.

Error in curlOptions(..., .opts = .opts) : unnamed curl option(s): HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Page not found

Page not found

Could you please suggest me on this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using SOAPUI, I am able to hit the intranet URL and able to get the response. But unable to do the same with RCurl, Anyone please suggest

Comment: Please suggest on below message> traceback()
9: stop(err)
8: stop.if.HTTP.error(http.header)
7: getURLContent(url, .opts = list(customrequest = "POST", ...), 
       curl = curl, post = 1L)
6: httpPOST("INTRANET URL", 
       userpwd = "USERID:PASSWORD")
5: merge(list(...), .opts)
4: rev(merge(list(...), .opts))
3: curlOptions(..., .opts = .opts)
2: curlSetOpt(..., .opts = .opts, curl = NULL, .encoding = .encoding)
1: curlPerform(httpPOST("INTRANET URL", 
       userpwd = "USERID:PASSWORD"), httpheader = headerfields, 
       postfields = body, writefunction = reader$update)

Answer (score 0):

I have used curl as below

reader = basicTextGatherer()
curl = getCurlHandle()

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), followlocation = TRUE, httpheader = c(Accept = "text/xml",Accept = "multipart/*",'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",SOAPAction="INTRANET URL"), userpwd = "USERID:PASSWORD", netrc = TRUE,timeout = 100, postfields = SOAP DETAILS, writefunction = reader$update, verbose=TRUE, curl = curl))

response <- getURL("INTRANET URL", curl=curl)